# flutter error connect data (something wrong. please try again later)

Tags: flutter, cpanel, logcat

my code source work good, but when I try to connect him whit new server whit cpanel in neamcheap I got this error in the emulator : something wrong. please try again later.

you can see the screen of the error in the Logic[image]

am tryin to run my flutter app whit new admin panel and I got problem of : 'something wrong. please try again later' in the emulator of both android and iOS